# How to use all CPU cores for Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

My scrapy program only uses one CPU core no matter how `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` i do. If or not some methods in scrapy can use all the cpu core just in one scrapy crawler?

ps: it seems have arguement `max_proc` to use in early edition, but i cannot find it now.

Comment: It seems that currently *max_proc* exists in Scrapy Service (scrapyd): https://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.12/topics/scrapyd.html ...

Comment: the latest version of scrapy is 1.4, can i use this feature now?

Comment: What I believe is that you can use that through scrapyd. I don't know if you can use that through ScrapingHub or not. But you can consider this instead:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests-per-domain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scrapy does not use multiple CPUs.

This is by design. Usually the bottleneck of Scrapy is not the CPU, but the network input/output. So, even using a single CPU, Scrapy can be more efficient that a synchronous framework or library (e.g. requests) used in combination with `multiprocessing`.

If CPU is a bottleneck in your case, you should consider having a separate, multiprocessing-enabled process handle the CPU-heavy parts.

If you still want to run Scrapy spiders in multiple processes, see [Running Scrapy from a script](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script). You can combine that with Python’s [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module. Or, better yet, using [Scrapyd](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or one of the [alternatives](https://scrapy-cluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/advanced/comparison.html).